# Save state of view of page in grails

Tags: javascript, html, grails

I have a page that is generated from a bunch of grails templates being rendered, with javascript widgets and stuff, that specify parameters for a search engine we are developing. The problem is, if someone clicks on a person returned in the search results and it takes them to another page, and then they hit the browser back button, the search parameters and dynamically created widgets and previous search results are all gone.

I dont really want to have to programmatically re-build the page based on the search parameters (which I can save as a session variable), and I would then have to re-run the search query again to get the results back. is there a way to save a page just as it was created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Popup a javascript window with information about that person instead of taking them to another page. In the worst case set the target of the person link to _new and that will force open a new browser window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

At some place the search parameters have to be saved. Either on server or client side. On the server side you only have the options `session` or `flash` scope.

On the client side you could store those values in a cookie. This needs some bits of javascript.

However theoretically the browser will keep manually changed form field-values out of the box. He is identifying the form fields by its name/id. It should not be necessary to do any programmatically things, except if you are loading some parts of the page via AJAX. Maybe you can doublecheck, that the input fields have static name/id pairs or you have some meta/cache/html settings, which prohibit such mechanism (double check, that your form does not have `autocomplete="off"` setting set. This will prevent the browser to refill your form fields.

Grails itself does not offer things like you need out-of-the-box (and I do not know if other frameworks have - maybe except for Seam, which has a concept of conversation scope; but even this feature will not work out-of-the-box if the user uses the browser back button). The easiest way is to make your search page some kind of cacheable (for the browser, by settings HTTP-headers or meta tags), so that the browser is not trying to reload the page from the server again, if the user presses the browser back button. And double check the `autocomplete="off"` setting.